# How to make a DIV section clickable?

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

I have written a web page in which links are all contained within their own  tags. I've also made them all button styles with CSS (border, background color, padding). How do I enable the whole DIV to be clicked to activate the link?

Comment: Some code would help...  It really depends on exactly what you mean and how you want to handle it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to do this kind of effect (making links act like buttons) is to apply css to the links themselves. Here's a basic example:

```
a.mylink {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
}
```

Test it out - the whole of the button is clickable. And it respects the browser's normal link actions like right-clicking, status url information, etc.

Comment: What might be new to some folks is adding the "display: block" to the link.  DIVs are "block" level by default, links are "inline".  If you want an inline element to act like a div (and other block elements) just give it a "display: block" like above.

Comment: Thanks. I was just about to ask a question that your comment showed me how to fix!

Comment: This won't work if the div you want to make clickable contains other divs since you can't embed divs inside of <a> tags.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is done in either of the following ways:

```
<div class='link_wrapper'>
  <!-- there could be more divs here for styling -->
  <a href='example.com'>GOto Example!</a>
</div>

.link_wrapper{
  somestyles: values;
  height: 20px; /*or whatever*/
  width:auto;
  padding:0px;
}
.link_wrapper a{
  line_height:20px; /*same as .link_wapper*/
  margin:0px;
}
```

Now the whole div is clickable.

Using Javascript this is also quite easy, this is using jQuery for easyness, however you could very easiyly do this without jQuery (if you do not already use it).

```
$('.link_wrapper')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer') //very important, indicate to user that div is clickable
  .click( function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  }); //Do click as if user clicked actual text of link.
```

I highly recommend putting an actual link in the DIV as non-javascript user will not be able to use the link if there is no actual link in the DIV.

Comment: This is pretty good but it doesn't show the url in the status bar when you hover over it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you had to write CSS for your "a" tags, instead of putting your links into divs and tunning divs with CSS.

Here is the example of the sidebar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

/*********************/
/* SIDEBAR */
/*********************/
#sidebar {
  width: 160px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#news {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-top: 1px dashed #294E56;
  border-right: 1px dashed #294E56;
}
#news li {
  display: inline;
}
#news .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  color: #666666;
}
#news a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #294E56;
  color: #73AFB7;
  line-height: 110%;
  background: #FFFFFF url(images/bg/bg_link.png) no-repeat right top;
}
/* hack for IE 6 < to make entire block clickable */
* html #news a {
  height: 1px; 
}

#news a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-image: url(images/bg/bg_link_h.png);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
<ul id="news">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Virgo: It's Your Month</span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Your Feedback </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">This Month's Survey </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Indoor lawns: sod or seed? </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Lorem Ipsum </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Dolor site amet </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Adipiscing elit </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Euismod tincidunt </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Dolor site amet </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="title">Dolor site amet </span>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see it in action here:
http://bazanov.net/sidebar

Comment: I wanted the whole thing to be clickable, the text, and the area around the text.

Comment: With pure CSS it is usually accomplished by using CSS for "a" tags and for spans inside "a" tags. I forgot about javascript solution, though, as J-P commented, user will not know if DIV is a link and is clickable.

Comment: PS. And the whole thing would be clickable with pure CSS. You just need to tune your "a" and inner "span" tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a div clickable. put an a tag inside it and display it as a block element and give it the same width and height as the div I do it all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can do something similar to what chustar suggested:

```
$(div#name).click(function(){
    window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href');
}).hover(function() {$(this).addClass('hovered')}, 
   function () {$(this).removeClass('hovered')});
```

Answer (score -3):

I figured out how to do it. In the  tag, create an onclick property then in that property, set window.location = (where you want to go).
As in:

```
<DIV OnClick="window.location='http://stackoverflow.com'">
    Content
</DIV>
```

Comment: Very bad practice! How exactly will the user know that the DIV is a link? Anchors are given a bunch of extra behavioural enhancements by browsers - the DIV element won't be enhanced in any way. This is really a case of usability, or lack thereof!

Comment: of course I'll have some other hints. They look like buttons, and when they mouse over, I'm setting the cursor to change to the selection thingy. This is just to show the solution I found the problem I had.

Comment: Look at the example Lance McNearney posted. That's exactly what you were looking for and it doesn't require javascript.

Comment: Voting up, this is a viable alternative solution